# Prepopulated fields following 'save as new' Django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django and have created a survey app. I have added prepopulated fields for my slug inside of admin.py which must be a unique value in the database and have added save_as = True in order to copy surveys. My problem is once a survey has been created and saved, if I wish to edit the name of the survey (and hence the slug of the survey), editing the survey name will not correspondingly update the slug without manually editing the slug field. I am wondering if it is possible to fix this such that when I edit the survey name, the slug field will update as well.

admin.py:

```
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = { "slug": ("name",),}
    fields = ['name', 'pub_date', 'description', 'external_survey_url','minutes_allowed', 'slug']
    inlines = [QuestionInline, SurveyImageInLine]
    save_as = True

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(Survey, SurveyAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
```

Comment: I would look at doing this inside a custom Form used for the model and override the save method. you might be able to do it in the SurveyAdmin overriding the `save_model` function.

Comment: Also, you can do it in Model save() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys, I was able to successfully override the model save() method which now correctly updates the slug when the name is updated..

models.py:

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.name
        super(Survey, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```